# animate parent before animate child

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, parent-child

I have a #parent that contains a #child which is hidden. when I hover over the #parent I want to [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) the child. That works.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#parent", function() {
    $(this).find("#child").fadeIn();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#parent", function() {
    $(this).find("#child").fadeOut();
});
```

Now, How can I first animate the #parent to the correct size, before the #child fades in?

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmNK3) to show what I mean.
Now, the #parent just "pops" when the #child is faded in.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `call back` of the parent,

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#parent", function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height": "50"
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).find("#child").fadeIn();
    })
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#parent", function () {

    var parent = $(this);

    parent.find("#child").fadeOut(500, function () {
        parent.animate({
            "height": "10"
        }, 500)
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/TmNK3/1/)

---

For your new requirement, you have to make use of the `.data()` to store the original height

just try,

```
var parent = $('#parent');
parent.data('height', parent.height());
var child = parent.find('#child').hide();

$(document).on("mouseenter", "#parent", function () {
    parent.animate({
        "height": parent.data('height')
    }, 500, function () {
        child.fadeIn();
    })
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#parent", function () {

    child.fadeOut(500, function () {
        parent.animate({
            "height": "10"
        }, 500)
    });
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/TmNK3/2/)

Comment: Ok, that works, but I wonder, if there is a way not to give static height values but the "actual" endheight.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy One more fixes need, When I continuously move my cursor then it's must stop or comlete last one before making new animation.